# Accessing JSON file with d3.js and Vaadin

Tags: json, d3.js, vaadin

I've read several Threads here on d3.js and JSON, I could not fix my problem though.

Please see the picture attached. I'm working with Vaadin and integrated d3.js into my project. I now owuld like to display a forced graph with d3.js, using a local graph.json file.

All code works - except accessing the .json file. 
The webapplication/website is displayed correctly, but the graph is empty/not there.
I assume the error lays somewhere here:

```
d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {...}
```

[please see picture here](http://i57.tinypic.com/29mumqc.jpg)

I'd appreciate any help. (inb4 new to javascript)

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Firebug gives me an error in line 80: TypeError: graph is undefined: .nodes(graph.nodes)

Comment: What does the `error` variable contain?

Comment: Don't know exactly what you mean. I don't see a field 'error variable'. //how to check error variable?

Comment: You are declaring `function(error, graph)` as your callback and accessing `graph` inside it. `error` contains any errors, which you should check to find out what's going on.

Comment: I assume this is what you mean: http://i57.tinypic.com/zxkxsw.png

Comment: That seems to suggest that your file isn't valid JSON.

Comment: My JSON file looks exactly like the JSON used here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558 - is that not valid?

Comment: Well that one is fine, but the invalid character error you're getting suggests that maybe something went wrong when downloading the file? I can only guess without a reproducible example.

Comment: Yeah that's my guess too, somehow the JSON file isn't loaded or can't be read, though its in the same directory and valid JSON.

Comment: "same" directory is a relative term.  in relation to where code from vaadin is delivered and where your conext is mapped etc.  check your network-tab in your web debuggin tool of choice (firebug, inspector, ...) and see if and where the graph.json is attemted to load from.  either your container does not send the file (404 error) because it's not there, where you app thinks it "relative" to or it might be  a problem of a wrong mimetype.

Comment: May be also check your access log files of the container for any "404" errors. That should indicate on the server side which actual URLs the d3.json call tries to access.

Comment: what version of vaadin and d3.js did you use?